# Openstreetmap usage for development

Tags: openstreetmap

Access to image at 'https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/0.png' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I was working on making a map, and for the first few days I had no trouble viewing OpenStreetMap without any problems. However, after a few days, I started getting the error indicated above.

Comment: There are already many similar questions. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using tile server, this problem is easily resolveable.
I used the "ol" npm package to integrate openstreetmap into my react application.

The method below allows us to change the tile server with ease.

```
  const tileLayer = new TileLayer({
        preload: 4,
        source: new OSM({url: 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.de/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'}),
    });
```